# Image not displaying in jsp

Tags: html, jsp

I have my image placed in a folder called images in the netbeans web pages folder and the link to it in my jsp is in a div as shown below:

```
<div id="image">
  <p>
    <img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/vote_image.GIF"
         alt="banner"
         width=600px
         height=300px
    />
  </p>
</div><!--end of image div-->
```

The problem is the image just doesn't load in the browser. What could be the problem? I used the same code in linux and it used to load the image. Could it be a browser problem, I'm using firefox 3.6 which I don't think should have a problem. Please let me know if any one has a clue as to why this is happening. If the problem is my code let me know how to adjust. Thank you

Comment: Please show the final generated HTML - the server-side source code is useless in this context. What does the URL look like? What happens if you call the URL manually in your browser?

Comment: http://getfirebug.com <-- this rocks. Explore the *Net* panel for HTTP traffic, here you can check if the image is successfully downloaded or not.

Comment: The generated source has `<img src="/MvsWeb/images/vote_image.GIF"
                         alt="banner"
                         width="600"
                         height="300"
                         />`. And manually loading gives error 404. I'm also getting a download error when trying to download firebug to my browser

Comment: Then the URL is just plain wrong or the image is not there where you expect it is. The URL is case sensitive, doublecheck it. The image has to be in the public webcontent folder of the deploy (but NOT in `/WEB-INF` folder), doublecheck it. By the way, you have still not accepted the answers on your previous questions: http://stackoverflow.com/users/759113/ken

Comment: @BalusC, I'm using netbeans 6.9.1 and I just created a folder called images under the web pages folder and that's where I placed my image. It is not in WEB_INF. And by the way, the answers given in my previous questions really worked, the problem is am still new and I don't know how to accept them like you put it. How is that done? Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

There are no units used in HTML width and height attributes.

```
<img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/vote_image.GIF"
     alt="banner"
     width="600"
     height="300"
  />
```

Without seeing the rendered source of the page, I'd guess that's your problem. If not, try inspecting your image in Firebug and post what its rendered source looks like.

Also, make sure case sensitivity is not in play: gif vs. GIF.